# postgresql case statement get another column value

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables: intrusion, alarms and CCTVs and I would like to use a case statement to obtain the registration_number of the object and its location, depending on whether it was a CCTV or an alarm that triggered an intrusion event in the intrusion table.

This is the intrusion table:

[image]

This is the alarm table:
[image]

The CCTV table is similar to the alarm table and this is my code:

```
SELECT
    ALARM_ID
,   CCTV_ID
,   CASE
        WHEN
            ALARM_ID    IS  NULL
        AND CCTV_ID IS  NOT NULL
        THEN
            (
                SELECT
                    REGISTRATION_NUMBER, LOCATION
                FROM
                    REMOTE_SECURITY.ALARMS
                WHERE
                    REMOTE_SECURITY.INTRUSIONS.ALARM_ID =   REMOTE_SECURITY.ALARMS.ALARM_ID
            )
        WHEN
            ALARM_ID    IS  NOT NULL
        AND CCTV_ID IS  NULL
        THEN
            (
                SELECT
                    REGISTRATION_NUMBER, LOCATION
                FROM
                    REMOTE_SECURITY.CCTVS
                WHERE
                    REMOTE_SECURITY.INTRUSIONS.cctv_id  =   REMOTE_SECURITY.CCTVS.CCTV_ID
            )
        ELSE
            'not running'
    END
FROM
    REMOTE_SECURITY.INTRUSIONS
```

I would like the final output to be a table with 2 columns: Location and Registration_number. (I dont need to know whether its a cctv or an alarm)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: some sample data and expected output for this data would be good.

Comment: Check your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then why not just do:

```
SELECT location, registration_number FROM alarms
  WHERE alarm_id IN (SELECT alarm_id FROM intrusions)
UNION
SELECT location, registration_number FROM cctvs
  WHERE cctv_id IN (SELECT cctv_id FROM intrusions)
```

this should be mostly equivalent to your code, just much more terse and closer to your stated intent

if you do intend to get information from the `intrusions` table, then maybe something like:

```
SELECT intrusion_id, datetime_occurred,
  COALESCE(a.location, c.location) AS location,
  COALESCE(a.registration_number, c.registration_number) AS registration_number
FROM intrusions i
  LEFT JOIN alarms a ON i.alarm_id = a.alarm_id
  LEFT JOIN cctvs c ON i.cctv_id = c.cctv_id
```

not sure what you're doing to get a syntax error, it works for me after I do:

```
create temp table intrusions (intrusion_id serial primary key, datetime_occurred timestamp, alarm_id int, cctv_id int);
create temp table alarms (alarm_id serial primary key, location text, registration_number text);
create temp table cctvs (cctv_id serial primary key, location text, registration_number text);
```

It helps if you include this sort of code in the question!  You'll get many more answers if you make it easier for other people…

Comment: thank you! your first suggestion works but I ran into an error for your second suggestion and I just want to find out why!

I got this error:

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "intrusions" Hint: There is an entry for table "i", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. Position: 298